# To add line break in snack bar Angular 4

Tags: angular, snackbar

I want to add multiline text message with proper line breaks that are provided by me.

```
  this.sampleStringErrorMsg = 'The sample is not valid:\n' +
            '- The key and key value are required in the sample.\n ' +
            '- The delimiter must be entered when the sample contains several key-value pairs.\n' +
            '- The delimiter must not be equal to the key or key value.\n';
```

`sampleStringErrorMsg` is the text I show in snackbar.
Right now snackbar ommit `\n` from the text and aligns the the whole message as shown in the image below
[image]

Answer (score 46):

I just added `white-space: pre-wrap`

// ts

```
const msg: string = `Registration successful. \n Please, confirm your email`;   
this._snackBar.open(msg, '', {
    duration: 8000,
    panelClass: ['success-snackbar']
});
```

//css

```
.success-snackbar {
  background: #1fcd98;
  white-space: pre-wrap
}
```

Comment: nice, this is really the simplest solution

Answer (score 9):

Your solution is to create a `snackbar` component.

Without seeing your code, I'm guessing you have roughly something like this:

```
this.snackBar.open(this.sampleStringErrorMsg, null, {
  verticalPosition: 'top'
});
```

As far as I'm aware, there's no way to achieve what you want by doing like the above.

1. Create a component. I'll call it `ErrorSnackBarComponent`. 
   On the `html` add the contents of your error message. It will look like something like this:

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <span>The sample is not valid:</span>
    <br/>
    <span>The key and key value are required in the sample.</span>
    <br/>
    <span>The delimiter must be entered when the sample contains several key-value pairs.</span>
    <br/>
    <span>The delimiter must not be equal to the key or key value.</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

2. Make sure the `ErrorSnackBarComponent` is referenced in the `app.module.ts` under:

   - declarations
   - entryComponents
3. Use your recently created `snackbar` component:

> ```
> this.snackBar.openFromComponent(ErrorSnackBarComponent, {
>     verticalPosition: 'top'
>   });
> ```

**Extra step**

If you want to pass data to the `ErrorSnackBarComponent`, change your snackbar component's constructor to this:

```
constructor(@Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: any) { }
```

and instead of 3., use this:

```
this.snackBar.openFromComponent(ErrorSnackBarComponent, {
    verticalPosition: 'top',
    data: <YOUR_DATA_HERE>
  });
```

and you should be able to use `data` from the `ErrorSnackBarComponent` and display your error message alongside with any other details such as properties.

[Here is the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview) for `snackbar` for your reference.

Comment: shows the html text as plain text

Answer (score 4):

My reputation is too low to comment directly. I suggest an addition to [Marias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13094234/maria-odintsova) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61404124/3071395).

I am using Angular v7.3.7 and had to add `::ng-deep`, when I placed the CSS in a components CSS file like this

```
::ng-deep .success-snackbar {
   background: #1fcd98;
   white-space: pre-wrap
}
```

in order for it to work. Alternatively you could add the CSS to the global `styles.css` file of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Coming late to the party ... but I have just had to solve this issue and found that creating a function that 're-builds' the string with newlines in works:

```js
  this.snackBar.open(
    this.toNewLineString(this.snackBarText), 'Close', {
    panelClass: "snack-bar"
  });

  toNewLineString(input: string) {
    var lines = input.split('\\n');
    var output = "";
    lines.forEach(element => {
      output += element + "\n";
    });
    return output;
  }
```

Comment: nice, its really replace the "\n" with space, but no create a true new line, any idea?

Comment: does not create new line